# How to align two containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to align two containers to the right edge of the upper container, but at the same time, it is necessary that they are centered. Don't know maybe I can use the calc function somehow?

```css
.container1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.container2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

I want like that:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWhoq.jpg)

Comment: You are using max width so I assume if the first element has very little text in it it will be one line and narrower. Is that right?

Comment: No, as you can see in the example there is no text in the container and it is not shrinking. Actually, I have a picture in the second container that goes beyond the general container of the entire page. To make an adaptive image, I need that when the browser window reaches the edges of that image, it also decreases along with the window. But when I use a negative margin-left, and try to shink windows, this left part of the image goes beyond of the browser window and does not shrink until it reaches the boundaries of the general page container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your code in a parent container and use `flex` and define a width on that parent. Then you can remove all margins you had set on containers 1 & 2 and use `margin: auto;` on `container2`, this will horizontally align this container. Finally, just add `align-items: flex-end;` on the new parent you created to align the first flex-item at the end.

```css
.container1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.container2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 1em;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
  <div class="container2">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But why do I need used margin: auto on container 2, even though align-items: flex-end already does right-edge alignment? And if I have alignment on the parent container margin: auto why do I need justify-content: center?

Comment: @Rinatster You would need `margin: auto;` to center container2 if there was not a dynamic width set on the parent container. But because it's set at `fit-content` it will fit the largest container which is container 2, so it is not necessarily necessary, but just good to have. It's there in case you were to add a dynamic width to the parent which is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think that flex is a great option. Here is another option just using an outer container that has `margin: auto;` to center the content.

```css
.container1 {
    padding: 1rem;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 3rem 0 3rem auto;
    border: 5px solid orange;
}

.container2 {
    padding: 1rem;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 3rem 0 3rem auto;
    border: 5px solid orange;
}

.new-container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-container">
  <div class="container1"></div>
  <div class="container2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should container on the parent by using a display: flex; and set container 1 & container 2 by margin:auto; w will align horizontally and then just add align-items: center;